# Suggest or choose a theme for the Fall 2013 GDSE Game Jam!

Tags: discussion, gamejam-2013-fall

At the beginning of the [GDSE Game Jam](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/the-first-gdse-gamejam) (November 1st, 12PM UTC), **the theme will be selected randomly from the top 10 voted themes**. At drawing time, I will sort the list by [votes](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/vote-for-your-favorite-theme-for-the-upcoming-gdse-game-jam?answertab=votes#tab-top), any ties for the top 10 will be randomly chosen from the tie group.

**Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.**

Rules for proposing a theme:

1. **One theme per answer**
2. The theme should be expressed **one to six** words. No details. Allow room for different interpretations. If you have to choose between specific and interesting, go with interesting.
3. You can propose as many themes as you want, please ensure you're not duplicating an existing theme.
4. Please make sure it's actually a theme, i.e. "Physics Puzzle" is a type of game, not a theme.

Don't get upset if you get down votes. It's part of the process.

You can register for the jam [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/10960/gdse-gamejam?tab=schedule), but it's not required to participate.

---

To make voting a little easier, you may want to sort the answers by [active](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/vote-for-your-favorite-theme-for-the-upcoming-gdse-game-jam?answertab=active#tab-top). Go through a vote on all your choices. Then, when you come back later, you can sort by [active](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/vote-for-your-favorite-theme-for-the-upcoming-gdse-game-jam?answertab=active#tab-top) again and just vote on the newest ones.

---

[image]

Comment: Feel free to add the voting reminder to your suggestions, to meet the minimum length requirements. But please don't add more details about your theme suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There can only be one.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 13):

### Mad scientist.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 12):

### Swarm

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 12):

### In the beginning...

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 10):

### Escape

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 10):

### Orbits.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 9):

### Evolution

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 7):

### The hero is the bad guy.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 6):

### Stack Overflow

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 5):

### In the end, you die.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 5):

### Most wanted.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 5):

### Time is broken.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 5):

### Blast

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Mutually assured destruction.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Dungeons / Caverns

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Go into the light.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### One last time.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### What have you done!?

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 4):

### Then everything changed.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Fight fire with fire.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Deception.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

## Transportation

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Past and Future.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### You can't take it with you.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Entropy

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Revenge.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Rainbow/Spectrum

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't

Answer (score 3):

### Pacifism

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 3):

### Negative Space

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### Winter is Coming

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

## The Greater Good

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

## Streets

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### Weakest link.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 2):

### The road less traveled.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### The fifth element.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

## Suicide.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

## Failing Senses

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### Portals.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### The darkness inside.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### God mode.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 1):

### [Ground Hog Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_%28film%29) / Time Loop

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Cards.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Night time.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Emergency!

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

## Access Denied

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Fact or Faith.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Is that your final answer?

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Once upon a time...

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

## The Source

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

## So Very Many

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -1):

### Big bets.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -2):

### **Halloween**

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -2):

## Ghosts.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -2):

### Take the long way home.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -4):

### Science vs Religion

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -5):

## The 60's.

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.

Answer (score -5):

### One last dream before...

Vote up the themes you want, vote down the themes you don't.